# Is the domain of symmetric derivative borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $\mu$ be the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $\lambda$ be a complex Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $S$ be the set of points $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\lambda (B(x,r))}{\mu (B(x,r))}$ exists in $\mathbb{C}$.

Then, is $S$ a Borel set? Moreover, is $\lambda (S)=0$?

Comment: I also posted this on : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1884629/44669

Comment: For future reference, simultaneous crossposts to Math.SE are frowned upon here.  They tend to lead to unnecessary duplication of effort.  Standard practice is not to crosspost until your question has gone unanswered for about a week.

Comment: @NateEldredge To make an excuse, I actually posted this a week ago on SE and I could not get any answer. So I deleted it and reposted it on SE and posted newly on overflow.

Comment: Well,  to delete and repost is also not appropriate.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh, okay. Sorry, I will be careful of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $S$ is Borel. Assume, to be specific, that $B(x,r)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

Lemma 1. The function $(0,\infty)\ni r\mapsto\ell(r):=\lambda (B(x,r))$ is left-continuous, for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Proof. By the Hahn decomposition theorem, $\lambda$ is a linear combination (possibly with complex coefficients) of nonnegative measures. So, in the rest of the proof of Lemma 1, without loss of generality (wlog) $\lambda$ itself may be assumed to be nonnegative. Take any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and then any $r\in(0,\infty)$. The sequence of balls $B(x,r-1/n)$ is increasing, with $\bigcup_n B(x,r-1/n)=B(x,r)$. So, $\lambda(B(x,r-1/n))\to\lambda(B(x,r))$. Since $\lambda$ is nonnegative, the function $(0,\infty)\ni r\mapsto\lambda (B(x,r))$ is nondecreasing. Now Lemma 1 follows.

Lemma 2. The function $\mathbb{R}^n\ni x\mapsto\lambda (B(x,a))$ is Borel, for each real $a>0$.

Proof. Wlog $\lambda$ is nonnegative in the proof of Lemma 2 as well. Take any real $c$. It is enough to show that the set $L_c:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon\lambda(B(x,a))>c\}$ is open (and hence Borel). To do this, take any $x\in L_c$, so that $\lambda(B(x,a))>c$. By Lemma 1, we can find some real $\delta>0$ such that $\lambda(B(x,a-\delta))>c$. But for all $y\in B(x,\delta)$ one has $B(y,a)\supseteq B(x,a-\delta)$ and hence $\lambda(B(y,a))\ge \lambda(B(x,a-\delta))>c$. So, for any $x\in L_c$ one has $B(x,\delta)\subseteq L_c$. Thus, indeed the set $L_c$ is open, and Lemma 2 follows.

We are now ready to show that $S$ is Borel.
Indeed, for any real $r>0$, let $Q_r:=\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,r)$, a countable set. 
Then, again by Lemma 1,
\begin{equation}
 S=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{a,b\in Q_{1/m}}
 \Big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon\Big|\frac{\lambda (B(x,a))}{\mu (B(x,a))}-\frac{\lambda (B(x,b))}{\mu (B(x,b))}\Big|<\frac1k\Big\} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and, by Lemma 2, the sets $\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon\Big|\frac{\lambda (B(x,a))}{\mu (B(x,a))}-\frac{\lambda (B(x,b))}{\mu (B(x,b))}\Big|<\frac1k\big\}$ are Borel. 
Thus,
$S$ is indeed Borel.

Of course, in general $\lambda(S)\ne0$. E.g., take $\lambda=\mu$. Then $\lambda(S)=\infty$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1884745/44669

Comment: Since the function given here is not continuous, you cannot take $Q_{1/m}$ to cover all reals.

Comment: The $Q_{1/m}$'s don't have to cover all reals. Indeed, it is easy to see that, if $f$ is a monotonic function and $g$ is a monotonic function positive on $(0,\infty)$, then $\lim_{x\downarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is the same as $\lim_{x\downarrow0,x\in\mathbb Q}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, both in terms of the value and the existence.

Comment: Oh I missed that you assumed nonnegativity. However, you cannot assume that $\lambda$ is nonnegative without loss of generality. Say $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of reals and $\{b_n\}$ and $\{c_n\}$ are sequence of nonnegative reals. Then $\lim a_n$ may exist even if $b_n$ and $c_n$ do not exist.

Comment: (When $a_n=b_n - c_n$)

Comment: I have added the point that the function $r\mapsto \lambda (B(x,r))$ is left-continuous. This should make everything work.

Comment: What do you mean by "left-contonuity" when the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$? And what do you mean by $(-\infty,c_1+x)$

Comment: The domain of the left-continuous function $r\mapsto \lambda (B(x,r))$ is the set of all positive real numbers (or, if you prefer, with the same effect, the set of all real numbers). By $(-\infty,c_1+x)$ I mean, as usual, the open interval from $-\infty$ to $c_1+x$.

Comment: No, for $(-\infty,c_1+x)$ to make sense, $x$ should be **real**, not an $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector. You are assuming $x$ to be *both* real and $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector in your answer.

Comment: Fixed that as well. It's late here. :-)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. However, I still don't get how you wlog assume that $\lambda$ is nonnegative as I said above. I understand that by Hahn decomposition theorem, $\lambda=\lambda^+ - \lambda^-$. However, it **can** happen that $\lim \frac{\lambda^+(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))}$ and $\lim \frac{\lambda^-(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))}$ **do not exist** while $\lim \frac{\lambda(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))}$ exists.

Comment: That $\lambda$ is nonnegative is assumed only **after (1) is established**, and (1) is establshed based on the left continuity of the function $r\mapsto \lambda (B(x,r))$, even when $\lambda$ is complex-valued. After that is done, we use three facts: (i) that $\lambda$ is a linear combination of nonnegative measures; (ii) that a linear combination of Borel functions is Borel; (iii) that the function $\mathbb{R}^n\ni x\mapsto\lambda (B(x,a))$ is Borel if $\lambda$ is a nonnegative measure.

Comment: Aha! Now I see what is going on here. I will check it again. Thank you :)

Comment: I have streamlined a bit the proof of the fact that the function $x\mapsto\lambda (B(x,a))$ is Borel.

Comment: All right. I am still trying to understand the left continuity part, but now you have deleted that part. Would you please add that part again?

Comment: Your example is incorrect: $\lambda((-r,r))$ is left-continuous in $r$ for any measure $\lambda$. I have added details in the proof of the left-continuity.

Comment: You are right, I was wrong. Now I clearly get your argument. Thank you for helping me. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. We can majorize $\lambda $ by a non-negative Borel measure $|\lambda|$. Let $\nu = |\lambda| + \mu .$ Since $|\lambda|$ and $\mu$ are absolutly continuos with respect to $\nu$, we can represent $\lambda $ and $\mu$ as 
   $$ d\lambda = L d\nu ,\\ d\mu = M d\nu $$ 
   for some Borel functions $L,M.$

$$\dots\dots\dots$$
2. Lebesgue differentiation theorem applies to $d\nu$, so
$$ \frac {\lambda(B(x,r))}{\nu(B(x,r))} = 
\frac{1}{\nu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} L(y)\space d\nu(y) 
\:\xrightarrow[r \rightarrow 0^+]{}\: L(x) \text{      a.e. $\nu$} $$
and
$$ \frac {\mu(B(x,r))}{\nu(B(x,r))} = 
\frac{1}{\nu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} M(y)\space d\nu(y) 
\:\xrightarrow[r \rightarrow 0^+]{}\: M(x) \text{      a.e. $\nu$} .$$

Note that 
$$0 \le \mu(M \le 0) = \int_{(M \le 0)} M(y)\space d\nu(y) \le 0 $$
therefore $ M > 0 \text{     a.e. $\nu$},$ so outside a Borel $\nu$-null set,
$$ \frac {\lambda(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))} = 
\frac {\lambda(B(x,r))/\nu(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))/\nu(B(x,r))}
\:\xrightarrow[r \rightarrow 0^+]{}\: \frac{L(x)}{M(x)} \text{      a.e. $\nu$} $$

$$\dots\dots\dots$$
3. Since $\nu(S^c) = 0$, then $\lambda(S^c)=0$, and even $|\lambda|(S^c)=0$ (i.e. any Borel subset of $S^c$ has null $\lambda$ measure).

$$\dots\dots\dots$$
4. I can't show that $S$ is Borel. If the measure $\lambda$ is such that the functions: 
$$ x \mapsto \lambda(B(x,r)) $$
($r>0$) are continuous, then $S$ is Borel. Since $\lambda$ might have singular support, these functions need not be continuous, but there might be some other way of showing $S$ is Borel.

Comment: How do you define $\lambda(S^c)$ if you cannot show $S$ is a Borel set?

Comment: $\lambda$ can be extended to the sigma algebra generated by Borel sets and $\nu$ null sets. The simplest way is to extend $\lambda$ as $\lambda^{ \star}(A) = \int_A L(y) \space d\nu(y) $.

Comment: [Wikipedia][1] mentions Federer's book. The results is that there is a Borel set $S_0$ contained in your set $S$ such that $\nu(S_0^c)=0$, since $S^c \subset S_0^c$, then $S = S_0 \cup \text{(a set contained in a $\nu$ null set})$   


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem